# GCC compiler online version for my website

Tags: gcc

I have a website teaching C for beginners.

I'm trying to have a C compiler online version so that a user could easily compile their code online itself.

Are there any compilers available? If available, which is the best one?

I have found some compilers, but they have got no capability of taking input from the user, but they have the capability of just displaying the output.

Comment: gcc generally compiles to native code, where are you going to run that native code?

Comment: try ideone.com, an online ide for many languages

Comment: @teambob actually i want to create a blog this time is that possible to do with a blogger site

Answer (score 2):

There is no package that can just be added to a blog so people can try C online and see the results.

You could provide a link to gcc or another compiler so your readers can try it themselves.

If you were really serious, a CGI script could be created on the server side which:

1. Runs in a sandbox (this is critical to get right and is potentially dangerous if done incorrectly)
2. Compiles the source code
3. Runs the compiled code
4. Returns the results

Sorry that I can't give you an easy answer, but there it is.